# java scanner keeps skipping a line whenever i input a value

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java.util.scanner, do-while

this is my first time posting a question here. I'm having a problem with the scanner method. this is the code I'm using

```
public void loanBook() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean successful = false;
        do {


            System.out.println(
                    "\nPlease enter the book ID of the book that you wish to take out (Press 9 to exit to the main menu)");

            if (input.nextInt() == 9) {
                successful = true;
                break;
            }
            int bookID = input.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < Books.size(); i++) {
                if (Books.get(i).getBookID() == bookID) {
                    do {
                        System.out.println("\nHow long would you like to loan the book for (20 Days maximum):");
                        int durationOnLoan = input.nextInt();
                        if (durationOnLoan <= 20 && 1 <= durationOnLoan) {
                            Books.get(i).setDurationOnLoan(durationOnLoan);
                            successful = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("The number of days you have entered is invalid");
                        }
                    } while (successful == false);

                    System.out.println("\nThe book " + Books.get(i).getTitle() + " is now on loan");
                    Books.get(i).setOnLoan(true);
                    Books.get(i).setNumOfLoan(Books.get(i).getNumOfLoans() + 1);
                    successful = true;
                }

            }
```

the project I'm working on is a library array list which holds book objects (the array list works fine).
The for loop is used to iterate through the library array list to see if the book is there.
 Whenever i run the program and enter a valid input for the book id, this happens

Please enter the book ID of the book that you wish to take out

101// this is my input which is valid

101// i have to enter it this second time for it to work and continue to the next piece of code

any thoughts? could it be a problem with the do while loop? or the for loop through the array list

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
if (input.nextInt() == 9) {
```

You read the number, and provided it's not 9, you continue.  But you also discard it. which is why you have to enter it again. A simple solution is to use a variable which is what you have done already.

```
int bookID = input.nextInt();
if (bookID == 9) // check the save value so you don't have to enter it twice.
    break;
```

If you are wondering, how could I have solved this myself?  The answer is to use your debugger as this will should exactly what each line of code is doing.